# Python allow users to edit code from Windows application

Tags: python, windows

I have an app that I'm sending to various users as a desktop application (converted from a python file to an application). In the event that users need to change/update the code, is there a way for them do it from the desktop application/file folder with dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec()` to run a string. You can open a file and execute it with `exec()`, so you can change code after compiling.

Example:

```py
file = open("yourfile.py", "r")
exec(file.read())
file.close()
```